# How to split in such a way that "\n" is also a new element in python?

Tags: python, split

I have a big string where there are multiple lines.
For example,

```
abc def
ghi hij
```

When I do .split() with the above string, I get as follows:

```
['abc', 'def\n', 'ghi', 'hih']
```

The output I want is,

```
['abc', 'def', '\n', 'ghi', 'hih']
```

There can be cases where .split() leads to:-

```
['abc', '\n', 'dsa\n\n\nkij', 'poi']
```

I want this actually as follow:

```
['abc', '\n', 'dsa', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'kij', 'poi']
```

I would like to have a simple python code.

Comment: Maybe look at `splitlines` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a much simpler regex for this using groups and `.findall()`, which will return a list of all matches from a source string for you

```py
>>> src = """abc def
... ghi hij
... """
>>> re.findall(r"([^ \n]+|\n)", src)
['abc', 'def', '\n', 'ghi', 'hij', '\n']
```

```py
>>> src = "".join(['abc', '\n', 'dsa\n\n\nkij', 'poi'])
>>> print(src)
abc
dsa


kijpoi
>>> re.findall(r"([^ \n]+|\n)", src)
['abc', '\n', 'dsa', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'kijpoi']
```

This works by finding every block of either

- greedy ranges of *not* space or `\n` (anything until one is found; this is an opportunity to include more characters like `\t` or to use `\s`, which is any "whitespace character")
- exactly `\n`

You could potentially also use `.finditer()` to make more efficient use in some generator, though it's likely to make your solution more complex

Comment: Nice solution - I like the approach. Just one comment: the regex is certainly simpler than what was necessary when calling `re.split`, although it would be good to make the answer self-contained - "much simpler" doesn't currently make sense without referring to the other answers.

Comment: When I do this, empty spaces are not there in the list

Comment: For example,- [''abc", "", "", "def"] , 2nd and 3rd elements are removed, I want to retain them as well.

Comment: What would be the input to obtain `["abc", "", "", "def"]`? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: seconded! @Abc1729 additionally, it would be helpful to know what character are you expecting an "empty space" to be and what the output of `repr()` on the source string is!

Comment: The input is as follows
"asd        sd  sd              sdf f   d  asd\nedf    "
(The text looks like a specific format.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression split: `re.split`

```
>>> a = 'abc def\nghi   hij\n\n\nsdf ste'

>>> re.split(r" +|(?=\n)|(?<=\n)", a)
['abc', 'def', '\n', 'ghi', 'hij', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'sdf', 'ste']
```

The regular expression that this is using says to split either on one or more spaces, or if the next or previous character is a newline (using lookahead and lookbehind assertions).

Comment: Which version regular expression are you using?
I am getting different result.
In this code, '\n' is attached to the end of a word for example:- "dddd\n"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split()` with lookarounds for `\n`:

```
import re
print(re.split(r'(?<=\n)(?!$)|(?<!^)(?=\n)| ', your_str))
```

Comment: OP also wants to split on spaces, but yes, regex is the way to go here.

Comment: The default behaviour with `split()` is to treat multiple spaces as a single delimiter, so I think it wants a `+` after the space in order to mimic that. Apart from that, I think we have basically equivalent solutions.

Comment: Exactly. It all depends on how you want to split around spaces... The question lacks some examples to come with a bullet proof solution though...

Comment: In this code, '\n' is attached to the end of a word for example:- "dddd\n"

Comment: Please add a few examples to your question (with input / desired output). I edited my answer to avoid splitting at the beginning/end of strings but I'm still not sure how you want to handle multiple white spaces or complex alternations of spaces and `\n`...